# Use Puppeteer to test a login form succeeds?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am using Puppeteer. I would like to write a test to check that the login form on my site works, and shows the user a "Welcome" page.

This is what I've got:

```
  it('should allow the user to log in', async function () {
    await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);
    await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);
    await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }),
    heading = await page.$eval('h1', heading => heading.innerText);
    expect(heading).to.eql('Welcome');
  });
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Error: Timeout of 25000ms exceeded.
For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;
if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

If I run the test with headless set to false, then I can see the form being submitted, and the welcome page loading. It is ready long before the 25000ms timeout.

I can see that it is the `await page.waitForNavigation` line that is failing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually it seems that if I just get rid of the `await page.waitForNavigation` entirely the test succeeds, and runs much faster. So perhaps this part isn't actually required!

Comment: `await page.waitForNavigation` ensures consistencies. I would recommend keeping it. However it shouldn't run that much faster. Don't hide the problem under the carpet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is that the code is asynchronous and there is no direct way testing framework knows that the test has finished.

To solve this problem test frameworks provide **done** method as a callback which can be invoked once you have finished your async task i.e. in your case when await is done.

You can rewrite the test case as below

```
  it('should allow the user to log in', async function (done) {
    await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);
    await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);
    await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }),
    heading = await page.$eval('h1', heading => heading.innerText);
    expect(heading).to.eql('Welcome');
    done();
  });
```

Don't forget to add done as a parameter in the test case function

async function (**done**)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `done()` callback (see [here](https://blog.revathskumar.com/2016/11/javascript-testing-promises.html)):

```
  it('should allow the user to log in', async function(done) {
        await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);
        await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);
        await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
        await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }),
        heading = await page.$eval('h1', heading => heading.innerText);
        expect(heading).to.eql('Welcome');
        done();
    }
  });
```

I'm not 100% sure you can define `async function` directly in `it` second arguments. You may need a vanilla callback and create an async function within it:

```
  it('should allow the user to log in', function(done) {
      (async() => {
        await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);
        await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);
        await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);
        await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }),
        heading = await page.$eval('h1', heading => heading.innerText);
        expect(heading).to.eql('Welcome');
        done();
      })()
    }
  });
```